# How to receive data from a server?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp, system.net

I'm coding a chat application with C# Windows Froms. My problem is that, my server can send messages to each connected client but only a client that sent a message can receive a response. I tried to create a function like ReceiveLoop() with an infinite loop inside or add a timer and call Receive() function for each tick but both were unsuccessful due to the app's crash.
How to get the data in real time? I attach my client's app code.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private string name;
    private Socket _clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    private void Namebt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Test(Nametb.Text)) Nametb.Text = "Nie wpisano nazwy!";
        else
        {
            name = Nametb.Text;
            Nametb.Clear();
            Nametb.Enabled = false;
            Namebt.Enabled = false;
            Messageslb.Enabled = true;
            timer1.Start();
            LoopConnect();
        }
    }

    private void LoopConnect()
    {
        int attempts = 0;
        while (!_clientSocket.Connected)
        {
            try
            {
                attempts++;
                _clientSocket.Connect(IPAddress.Loopback, 100);

            }
            catch (SocketException)
            {
                Messageslb.Items.Clear();
                Messageslb.Items.Add("Connection attempts: " + attempts.ToString());
                Messageslb.Refresh();
            }
        }
        Messageslb.Items.Add("Connected!");
        Messageslb.Refresh();
        Messagetb.Enabled = true;
        Sendbt.Enabled = true;
    }

    private bool Test(string text)
    {
        if (text != "") return true;
        return false;
    }

    private void Sendbt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Test(Messagetb.Text)) Messagetb.Text = "Nie wpisano zadnej wiadomosci!";
        else
        {
            Send();
        }
    }
    private void Receive()
    {
        if(_clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize > 0)
        {
            byte[] receivedBuffer = new byte[1024];
            int rec = _clientSocket.Receive(receivedBuffer);
            byte[] data = new byte[rec];
            Array.Copy(receivedBuffer, data, rec);
            Messageslb.Items.Add(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data));
        }         
    }

    private void Send()
    {
        string message = "[" + name + "]: " + Messagetb.Text;
        Messagetb.Clear();
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
        _clientSocket.Send(buffer);
        Receive();
    }

    private void Nametb_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return) Namebt_Click(sender, e);
    }

    private void Messagetb_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return) Sendbt_Click(sender, e);
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Receive();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to derail your question, if you're seriously looking to learn the low level communications protocols. If you're just after a solution, check out the [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) library for creating a chat application.

Comment: Now, if you want to receive multiple server messages in your loop, you already explained yourself what you have to do: send client message -> receive server message -> send client message -> receive server message -> ...rinse & repeat. Furthermore, you not telling us any more than just that your program crashed is not giving us any information that could help us helping you. (Two guys talking; guy One: "_My car is broken. How to fix?_" Guy Two: "_Dunno... How is it broken?_" One: "_Why do you need to know? Can't you just tell me how to fix it?_" Two: "_Okay, i know how to fix. Buy a new car_")

Comment: @elgonzo by "crash" i mean the program doesn't respond because it turns into infite loop. I can't even close a program by clicking "X" button in the top-right corner or "Stop compiling" button. i must turn off the proceess in the task manager.

Comment: did you try to increase the interval for the timer ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean with "Stop compiling" button. The compiler is not involved in running a program. I guess you mean the button stopping the debug session. Thus, are you sure you started the program in the debugger; i.e., is the "Stop debuggin" button enabled?

Comment: @Vishnu yes, it was set to 100 by default and i set it to 1000 but even this didn't work

Comment: @elgonzo you're right, my mistake. it's "stop debugging" button. i tried to start the program with tht debuger and without it as well

Comment: Note that you only do Receive in the loop which is in violation of the simple client-server protocol you explained. It could be that some part of the network driver stack is waiting for something to come from the server (but which is not coming) and thus effectively blocking your program (and debug session). (just a guess of course, but the obvious problem to fix first is to change your timer-based loop to adhere to the communication procedure your explained here)

Comment: ok so i'll try to do Send in the loop but sending an empty string and try to receive only if  resposnse is anything beside an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the receive method on a separate task.

```
_clientSocket.Receive(receivedBuffer);
```

should be:

```
private Task _receiving;
private void Receive()
{
  if(_clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize > 0)
    {

    if(_receiving == null || _receiving.IsCompleted)
     _receiving = Task.Run(() => 
     {
        byte[] receivedBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int rec = _clientSocket.Receive(receivedBuffer);
        byte[] data = new byte[rec];
        Array.Copy(receivedBuffer, data, rec);
        Messageslb.Items.Add(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data)); 
     });

 }
}
```

Otherwise clientSocket.Receive will hang your program.

You will want to make sure Messageslb is thread safe though, that will take further research.

If you're looking for real time communication look into RTC Client for C# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms946701.aspx.  Otherwise I would highly recommend Socket.IO since it is truly simple to use and set up with extremely fast rtc! https://socket.io/get-started/chat